# extend function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to query and trying to understand what below plugin function is doing, but not clearly understanding.

```
var pluginName = 'Widgets';

function Plugin(element, options) {
    /**
     * Variables.
     **/
    this.obj = $(element);
    this.o = $.extend({}, $.fn[pluginName].defaults, options);
    this.objId = this.obj.attr('id');
    this.pwCtrls = '.jarviswidget-ctrls'
    this.widget = this.obj.find(this.o.widgets);
    this.toggleClass = this.o.toggleClass.split('|');
}
```

I would be really thankful if some one who is great in Jquery could explain it step by step.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Mona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) merges the contents of two or more objects together into the first object.

In other words, it takes an object with default settings for the plugin, then gets the object passed in as the `options`, and joins them together so that the options overwrite the defaults.

Example

```
var defaults = {
    setting1 : '2',
    setting2 : true
}

function plugin(options) {
    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    /* settings now contain

    {
        setting1: '2',
        setting2: false
    }
    */
}

plugin({
    setting2: false // this is the options, they change the default settings
});
```

The `Plugin` function itself seems to be part of some sort of widget to build plugins, where it just sets a few general settings to the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the function of Java?

```
public class ClassName extends ClassName2 {
   // class code here
}
```

Which means, that the `ClassName` would be using the properties and methods of `ClassName2`.

Similarly, this method is used to merge the contents of two object together in the first object just like Java's method.

In your code, the `this.o` would now have the value of `fn[pluginName].defaults`. It is just like copy pasting data from the second parameter to the first one. In JavaScript you're dealing with **Objects** so everything here is an Object. Second object's data is transfered to the first Object.

Another method of using this function is like this

```
// Merge object2 into object1
$.extend(object1, object2);
```

More here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/